# Can I use BufferedReader and BufferedInputStream together?

Tags: java, io, inputstream

I just wonder if I can use BufferedReader and BufferedInputStream together?

for example, I create a socket and read some data from server, assume I use default charset. Can I code like this?

```
Reader reader = new BufferedReader(
                      new InputStreamReader(
                          new BufferedInputStream(
                               socket.getInputStream)));
```

Or should I only use one of these two class at a time? Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can, but it's pointless. There is no advantage. Just use the `BufferedReader`. It will read from the `InputStreamReader` in 4K chunks, possibly more by now, so the `InputStreamReader` doesn't have any efficiency issues such as decoding one `char` at a time.

Comment: The only way this could help is if more buffers aid the application, and if that works then it's probably best to just increase the buffer size of the BufferedInputStream, rather than wrap the object.  Also look at using NIO instead, and using direct buffers (and large ones, 64k is good if you want good speed) directly on the InputStream.

Comment: @markspace - It probably won't work as a way to provide "more" buffering.  When the `BufferedReader` runs out of characters, it will issue a large `read` request down the pipeline.  Depending on the relative buffer sizes, file encodings, etc, this could be satisfied without reading from the OS, or it could require 1, 2 or many OS read calls.

Comment: *"assume I use default charset"* - That's not helpful.  The default charset could be anything, and the actual charset could actually matter.